# Flyout Settings Design Windows 8.1

Tags: caliburn.micro

In the `Caliburn.Micro Version 2.0` I can create a new `Settings` flyout like this:

```
settingsService.RegisterFlyoutCommand<SettingsViewModel>("Custom");
```

How can I change or set the `Back Color` and `Header` of the setting flyout?

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterFlyoutCommand()` takes viewSettings for this purpose. You can set the properties available on `SettingsFlyout`:

```
var viewSettings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
viewSettings["HeaderBackground"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
settingsService.RegisterFlyoutCommand<SettingsViewModel>("Custom", viewSettings);
```

Comment: what about settings such as `Uid`, `Style` or `BackClick`?